# QGIS reading Sentinel 2 image .zip gives error?

Tags: qgis, raster, sentinel-2

I have a very primitive question. 
The sentinel-2 .zip tiles downloaded from Copernicus Open access Hub are being recognized and opened with STEP SNAP toolbox (obviously)! However this is not necessarily true with QGIS 3.4. When I try to open the same .zip file with QGIS I receive an error : Raster Layer Provider is not valid

I wonder if it is something wrong with the GDAL attached to QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Well in general I think, unlike the sentinel-1 products which are being opened by directly reading the .zip/.SAFE files, in sentinel-2 case one is better to unzip the archive and directly give the address of the interesting band which means:

selecting folders : Granule-> ... -> IMG_DATA

and then choosing the interesting band(s).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a Sentinel 2 image and tried it.  Most files listed by QGIS 3.4 give that error, but if I add MTD_MSIL2A.xml it shows the raster image in QGIS.

[image: Sentinel 2 image in QGIS 3.4]